# Consecutive anchored matching with java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, regex

I would like to implement the following semantics:

```
while (EOF is not reached) {
    if (scanner.findWithinHorizon("^" + pattern1, 0)) {
        // do something
    } else if (scanner.findWithinHorizon("^" + pattern2, 0)) {
        // do something else
    } else {
        // report error
    }
}
```

Okay. The problem here is that `Scanner` doesn't match the new "head of the stream" with an anchored regex. For example, let's say we have a scanner `new Scanner("11")`. The first time we match it against the regex `^1` by calling `scanner.findWithinHorizon("^1", 0)` will return the matched string `"1"`. However, the second call will return `null`, instead of the behavior I want, which will be returning `"1"` again because the new head of the stream is still `'1'` after consuming the first `'1'`.

Is there any way I can get the effect I want in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trying to understand your  question , you want to match '1', you passed in '11'.  you want a solution to match the first '1' and then the second '1' ?

Comment: Hi Ibukun. Yes. I'd like to elaborate more. Say we have '123'. If I match '2' it will be a match. But I want it to be a match only if I've matched '1' before it.

Answer (score 0):

> Say we have '123'. If I match '2' it will be a match. But I want it to
>   be a match only if I've matched '1' before it
>   "

what you need is a lookbehind operator, this allows you to match a character based on it previous character. 
(?=) - positive lookahead
(?<=) - positive lookbehind

if you want to match based on what is ahead also, you can use lookahead.

Here is an answer already [Implementing look behind in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

Look behind Positive(?<=)

Find expression A where expression B precedes

Comment: Thank you, Ibukun. I think I need to rephrase. I expect the regex only matches a `prefix` of the (string represented by the) scanner.